# Question regarding Sharepoint 2010 patching

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, cumulative-update, patching, farm-admin

I have SharePoint production and staging environment where production has build version of 14.0.7015.1000 & staging has 14.0.7125.5000. I had observed there are two additional hot fixes applied on staging(February 2014 CU, June 2014 CU for SharePoint 2010) which were not present in production environment.

How do I make production build version same as staging. Does installing above CU will make both the farms at same build version? .

Do I need to install just June 2014 CU on production or I need to install first February CU and then June 2014 CU?

I have 3 WFE, Should I install the CU at different time on each WFE? What would be down time?

Do I need to do any backup, what is way to restore if something doesn't work after installation of CU?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the Answers:

Does installing above CU will make both the farms at same build version?.  **Yes**

Do I need to install just June 2014 CU on production or I need to install first February CU and then June 2014 CU? **You just need to Install June 2014 CU( this CU include the previous CUs as well.)**

have 3 WFE, Should I install the CU at different time on each WFE? **As best practice, you should install CU binaries on all server in parallel, after that you have to run the Config wizard on each Server in farm. Config wizard should run on one server at a given time. i would start from central admin server.**

What would be down time? **depend upon the size of content and number server, Farm will not available during the updates and config wizard. You should plan it accordingly.**

Do I need to do any backup, what is way to restore if something doesn't work after installation of CU? **as a Best practice, RUn Full back of the Farm depend upon you backup method...either SharePoint or Database Backup If some things goes wrong at the end, its depend upon the corruption, if whole farm went down then you need to rebuild it. or if one database corrupted then you need to just restore that db.**

Comment: Thanks Waqas Sarwar MCSE .. Do you have a reference links or documents for performing above tasks.??

Answer (score 0):

I am working on assignment to update Sharepoint 2010 Farm Servers ( app and WFE servers) Patch update from SP1 to latest one, can you please guide what should be the steps.

```
Please correct me if I am wrong; that CU will include all the old patches update including SP2 ?

Do I need to install Dec 2019 Updates ( is it the last and latest CU update available) or I have to install all the updates, as mentioned on this link for 2010 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates


Somwhere I find below steps for installing patch updates on SharePoint Servers, please correct me if I am wrong:

1)  Download the CU and document the issues it is purported to resolve
2)  Install the CU on a non-production environment FIRST and TEST IT!!
3)  Prepare the production SharePoint environment
4)  Document the production environment BEFORE patching
5)  Dismount ALL SharePoint content databases
6)  Install the CU on each farm server
7)  Run PSConfig on all servers
8)  Re-mount all content databases
9)  Ensure ALL content databases have been re-mounted successfully
10) Run content database upgrade script(s)
11) Document the production SharePoint environment AFTER patching
12) Verify production farm functionality
```